# Disappearing thunderbird file during drag-and-drop to Application

Tags: file, drag-and-drop, handle, thunderbird

I'm trying to develop an application that can process a file drag-and-dropped from thunderbird to the applications icon. (Win7 64bit, vs2008, .Net3.5)
I'm using the My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(0).ToString() to find out what file has been dropped to my icon. 
Since its a dragged file, the location points to somewhere in my Temp directory. At start I copy this temp eml file, to another folder to process.
I'm doing this at my Forms HandleCreated event.
This works most of the time, but 20% of the time the Temp file is gone by the time I try to copy it. I'm guessing its too fastly deleted by the Drag process Ending. 
Can you suggest me any solution that handle the file faster, or keep the temp file after drag for a few sec in windows?